# LINQ Convert and Filter List Part 2

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Would like to both filter and convert a List. Is this the proper syntax?   Filter on type and property.

```
FieldDefEnum1 : FieldDef 

List<FileDef> fieldDefs

public List<FieldDefEnum1> FieldDefsEnum1
{
    get
    {
        return FieldDefs.OfType<FieldDefEnum1>().ToList().Where(fd => fd.SysCus == enumSysCus.Cus).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove that extra `.ToList()` in the middle of your expression - not necessary

Comment: It works but it is more by guess than a real understanding of LINQ.  I just wanted to know if it is proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work fine but you have redundant `.ToList()` in the middle that will break deferred execution. try this:

```
FieldDefs.OfType<FieldDefEnum1>().Where(fd => fd.SysCus == enumSysCus.Cus).ToList();
```